# python ensure file consistency

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, file-io

I have a Python 2.7.x process running in an infinite loop that monitors a folder in Ubuntu server.

Whenever it finds a file, it checks the file against a set of known files that have been processed already, and acts accordingly. In pseudocode:

```
found = set()
while True:
   for file in all_files("<DIR>"):
      if file not in found:
         process_file(file, found)
```

How can I make sure that the file hasn't just begun being copied there? I wouldn't want to say, take MD5 sum of file or open it with another process until I'm sure it's all there and ready.

Comment: You should really use inotify (and its Python bindings, pyinotify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest solution is to use the Linux kernel's [`inotify`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) API via the [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify) library. Experiment with the `IN_CREATE` and `IN_MOVED_TO` events depending on your needs. Also note [this blog post](http://www.serpentine.com/blog/2008/01/04/why-you-should-not-use-pyinotify/) warning of some implementation problems with the pyinotify library.

Answer (score 2):

Due to locks and other system-level operations, you will not be able to do anything to the file until it has completed copying.

A file cannot be in two operations at once.